# How do I filter API results by a related model attribute using Tastypie?

Tags: django, tastypie

Given the following API definition I need to be able to filter Events by Product Alias.

Given that an Event belongs to a Job and a Job belongs to a Product I'm not sure how to spec that.

api.py:

```
class ProductResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        queryset = Product.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'product'
        allowed_methods = ['get']
        excludes = ['created_at','updated_at']
        filtering = {
            'alias': ALL
        }

class EnvironmentResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        queryset = Environment.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'environment'
        allowed_methods = ['get']
        excludes = ['created_at','updated_at']

class JobResource(ModelResource):

    product = fields.ForeignKey(ProductResource, 'product')

    class Meta:
        queryset = Job.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'job'
        allowed_methods = ['get']
        excludes = ['created_at','updated_at']

class EventResource(ModelResource):

    environment = fields.ForeignKey(EnvironmentResource, 'environment',full=True)
    job = fields.ForeignKey(JobResource, 'job',full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Event.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'event'
        allowed_methods = ['get']
        excludes = ['created_at','updated_at']
        filtering = {
            HOW DO I FILTER BY PRODUCT ALIAS????
        }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Given the following filtering specs:

```
# In EventResource
filtering = { 
   'job' : ALL_WITH_RELATIONS
}

# In JobResource
filtering = { 
   'product' : ALL_WITH_RELATIONS
}

# In ProductResource
filtering = {
    'alias' : ALL
}
```

You should be able to do:

```
/api/events/job__product__alias=something
```

Comment: I see how that should work, but I'm getting a syntax error on the product filter in the JobResource.

Comment: `SyntaxError at /
invalid syntax (api.py, line 34)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 1.3.1
Exception Type: SyntaxError
Exception Value: 
invalid syntax (api.py, line 34)`

Comment: My bad - in dictionaries there should be colons `:` instead of equality signs `=`. Modified my answer accordingly :) So at line 34 you should have `'product' : ALL_WITH_RELATIONS` instead of `'product' = ALL_WITH_RELATIONS`

Comment: Damn...I should have noticed that too. Thanks man...that did it. I'm all set!!

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to achieve this is by [Advanced Filtering](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#advanced-filtering). This avoids many queries generated by tastypie ForeignKey fields. For security, remember to validate or clean your filter input data manually before adding data to `orm_filters`.

```
class EventResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        queryset = Event.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'event'
        allowed_methods = ['get']

    def build_filters(self, filters=None):

        if filters is None:
            filters = {}

        orm_filters = super(EventResource, self).build_filters(filters)

        # Your filtering
        if 'job__product__alias' in filters:
            orm_filters['job__product__alias'] = filters.get(
                'job__product__alias')

    return orm_filters
```

Them you should be able to get the filtered results doing:

```
/api/events/?job__product__alias=something
```